# about forms authentication and redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, forms-authentication

Every time I try to `Response.Redirect("tothepageIwant.aspx");` tt takes me to `~/Account/Logon.aspx`

Why is this happening? I'm using Forms Authentication, with a custom method of authenticating, using `PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials`.

If the credentials are valid, I want to Redirect.Response to the page I'm allowing the user to reach.

Instead, anytime I successfully login, it redirects me to the old `Account/Logon.aspx`.

Any suggestions? Anything I need to look out for when using Forms Authentication with custom method of authenticating?

EDIT (add code):

```
    protected void Submit1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var auth = new AuthClass();
        var result = auth.ValidateCredentials(UserEmail.Text, UserPass.Text);
        if (result)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Members/RollReport.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Msg.Text = "Not authorized to access this page.";
        }
    }

    public bool ValidateCredentials(string user, string pass)
    {
        using (var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "Domain.name"))
        {
            // validate the credentials
            try
            {
                var isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(user, pass);
                if (isValid)
                {
                    var isAuth = AuthorizeUser(user);
                    return isAuth;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (ActiveDirectoryOperationException)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    private bool AuthorizeUser(string user)
    {
        var isAuth = false;
        var authList = (List<string>)HttpContext.Current.Cache["AuthList"];
        foreach (var id in authList)
        {
            if (id == user)
            {
                isAuth = true;
            }
        }
        return isAuth;
    }
```

Comment: it has to do with the code logic in one or both of the Page_Load events... perhaps showing some code would help us to see where you are going wrong.. you can do this easier using Session variables that you initialize in the `OnSessionStart()` event inside the `Global.asax` file along with using PrincipalContext` properly..

Comment: I edited with authentication method code.

Comment: I'm not necessarily having issues authenticating. to be honest, I'm not sure I have the idea right using Forms Authentication with my custom method.

Comment: you're making it toooooo damn complicated if you are validating against `AD / LDAP` you can do all of this with the example I have posted I use it all the time with or without FormsAuthentication...

Comment: okay. now I'm being told to validate against AD/LDAP. 
My forms authentication is not meant to protect every .aspx page in my project.
It's just meant to protect one page, so would creating a Session["username"] really be what I need.
This authentication method is only for one user and for one function (deleting a sql table).

Comment: wouldn't that be a SQL User that would have specific Delete rights setup bt the DBA.. then in theory all you would need to do is run the command and or check the user to see if they have delete rights if so..then delete..else show an alert message stating that they do not have delete rights..

Comment: that might be something i need to look into. i appreciate the help. thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var userName = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];//or some other method of capturing the value from the username
var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
var userFind = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName);
if(userFind != null)
{
   HttpContext.Current.Session["username"] = userFind.DisplayName;
}
```

If you want to check and redirect.. store the value inside a session variable inside the `Global.asax`

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //declare and Initialize your LogIn Session variable
   HttpContext.Current.Session["username"] = string.Empty;
}
```

On the Page_Load of your login page assign the value if the code above succeeds

```
   if(HttpContext.Current.Session["username"] == null)
    {
       //Force them to redirect to the login page 
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("tothepageIwant.aspx");   
    }
```

`if you want to do the same thing inside a using(){} statement`

```
string fullName = null;
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context,"yourusernamehere")) //User.Identity.Name
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
            fullName = user.DisplayName;
        }
    }
}
```

use the debugger and inspect all of the `user.` `Properties` ok

Comment: I was giving this a try. Now, is there something I'm not doing? I initialize the Session["username"] and when Response.Redirect, the session is coming up as " ".

Comment: there is a difference between `HttpContext.Current.Session vs Session["username"]` also can you give me an example as to how you are  passing the username.. is it username or domain\username ?

Comment: the first 3 lines in the code can be tested stand alone by harcodeing the username.. it's pretty straight forward in regards to seeing if the `userFind` variable returns the expected value..

Comment: Ah I see, it makes sense. Again, thanks for your time and help.

Comment: I will post an even easier / compact way of doing the same thing within a `using` statement

Comment: awesome. that's great.

what if a user somehow gets to the page I'm protecting without logging in (by entering URL)? is there a way to confirm the Current.Session[username] to make sure they logged in?

Comment: yes this is why you would set the session variable `OnSessionStart` if coded properly they will not be able to I've had concerns of that before but was able to properly code for that.. the `HttpContext.Current.Session["username"]` is the driver.. you can do lots more with this to insure that the session variables are null when session ends etc..